# Comma before "which" and after "unable to do so"

Tags: commas, non-restrictive

I'm having trouble deciding if "I estimate to be $10,000.00" is a non-restrictive or restrictive phrase, and therefore the need for a comma surrounding this phrase.

In addition, is a comma required after "unable to do so"?

"The problem lies in generating the necessary capital to make a down payment, which I estimate to be $10,000.00, and I worry that if I am unable to do so, my plan to pursue the opportunity presented before me may be in jeopardy."

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to get all of that information into a single sentence?

Comment: Not necessarily...

Comment: If I change it to the following, do I need a comma before "which"? "The problem lies in generating the necessary capital to pay for first and last months rent, which I estimate to be $2,200.00. I worry that if I am unable to do so, my plan to pursue the opportunity presented before me may be in jeopardy."

Comment: Yes, the comma separates "which..." into a subordinate clause.

Comment: *You* determine if it's restrictive or nonrestrictive. There is no objective necessity of either. It depends entirely on what you are trying to *convey*. (And once you determine your intention, then you use the appropriate syntax and punctuation to express that.)